# I had installed perl module, parse::recdescent, still I m getting module not installed error

Tags: perl, unix, scripting, installation

I m trying to create charts for excel from perl script.
I have perl 5.22 version.
I installed perl module parse-recdescent.
I can verify its presence in my Unix  box with the command instmodsh.. And I can see this module installed.
I had successfully set the path for perl5lib.
But still when my script comes at      chart->add_series() function, its failing with error below

The Parse::recdescent module must be installed in order to write an excel formula at line x

I had installed this module same as all other modules which works fine.
All paths looks correct...

Please help me.

**Update:**

Error message: "The Parse::RecDescent module must be installed in order to write an Excel formula at charts4.ps line xxx

Here you can see i installed perl modules and Parse::RecDescent is there. I used instmodsh command...

Installed modules are: Parse::RecDescent

i am using PERL5LIB to set the paths of all modules..

my PERL5LIB looks like below:

```
/home/xxx/perl/Parse-RecDescent-1.967013/blib/lib/Parse
```

and you can see .pm is there in this path

```
$ cd /home/xxx/perl/Parse-RecDescent-1.967013/lib/Parse
$ ls -ltr total 440 -rw-r--r-- 221678 Sep 27 12:28 RecDescent.pm
```

FYI - This unix box has already a perl installed.. but i had installed my own version. and when i type perl -v it is giving my own version.. perl 5 vesrion 22 as expected. and i had installed many modules in the same way and all are working fine. except this... Want to know whats going wrong?

Comment: Please provide 1) the actual error message, 2) the output of `perl -E'say for @INC'`, and 3) the complete path to `RecDescent.pm`.

Comment: Modulenames are case-sensitive ... your error message hints that you mistyped the modulename.

Comment: Please don't trash your own question. That's not very useful for people who come along later looking for help with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

> i am using PERL5LIB to set the paths of all modules..
>
> my PERL5LIB looks like below:
>
> /home/xxx/perl/Parse-RecDescent-1.967013/blib/lib/Parse
>
> and you can see .pm is there in this path
>
> $ cd /home/xxx/perl/Parse-RecDescent-1.967013/lib/Parse $ ls -ltr
>   total 440 -rw-r--r-- 221678 Sep 27 12:28 RecDescent.pm

Some weirdness here. You say that you have installed Parse::RecDescent, but this doesn't look like an installed version. This looks like a directory that is used as part of the installation process, not the final result. How did you install the module?

But despite the fact that this isn't really where you should be using this module from, it should still work if you set `PERL5LIB` correctly. You have an extra `Parse` on the end of your directory. As the module is in `Parse/RecDescent.pm` the correct value for `PERL5LIB` will be `/home/xxx/perl/Parse-RecDescent-1.967013/blib/lib/`.

I really recommend that you install this module properly.

Comment: Thanks Boss... (Cross)  changing PERL5LIB to /home/xxx/perl/Parse-RecDescent-1.967013/blib/lib/ worked.. I am always thinking that i need to give till  /home/xxx/perl/Parse-RecDescent-1.967013/blib/lib/Parse/ ..... by the way it was installed correct only and its working now. path issues

Comment: It is not installed correctly. You are using it from the working directories for the installation process. The `blib` in the path is a complete giveaway. But anyway, if my answer was useful, then please upvote or accept it.